# Pass list object in Mockmvc using JUint5

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I'm using JUnit5 for my integration testing. I have a list of objects which needs to be passed to the endpoint. The content parameter of Mockmvc takes an only string. How can I pass this object? Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    Customer cust1 = Customer.builder().name("Syed")
            .location("India").build();
Customer cust2 = Customer.builder().name("Ali")
            .location("India").build();

    
    List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(cust1, cust2); --> This needs to be passed. 
    
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/process")
            
            .content(customers) --> Compilation error here
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that content() method expects JSON String or byte[] array.
You could have your TestUtil(using Jackson objectMapper) for your mockmvc tests:

```
public final class TestUtil {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();

    /** MediaType for JSON UTF8 */
    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8;

    private static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }

    /**
     * Convert an object to JSON byte array.
     *
     * @param object the object to convert.
     * @return the JSON byte array.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }

         /**
         * Convert an object to JSON String.
         *
         * @param object the object to convert.
         * @return the JSON String.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static String convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
Customer cust1 = Customer.builder().name("Syed")
            .location("India").build();
Customer cust2 = Customer.builder().name("Ali")
            .location("India").build();

List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(cust1, cust2); --> This needs to be passed. 

MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/process")
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(customers))
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
```

Comment: Why are you using convertObjectToJsonBytes method?

Comment: Syed , you could do writeValueAsString(). It's no matter for tests reason:)

Comment: I didn't get your point of using "writeValueAsString". IN your code, you are using writeValueAsBytes. Which one should be used?

Comment: Syed, could be used one of them. No matter which

Comment: I will check this and get back to you.

Comment: How can I convert from String to POJO?

Comment: Syed mapper.readValue(stringJsonOrByteArray, Customer.class);

Answer (score 1):

You can autowire `ObjectMapper` and convert your object (`customers`) to a string:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper;

// in your method
.content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customers))
// ..
```

Full example:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/process")

    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customers)) // change applied
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andReturn();
```

This assumes you have `jackson` in your classpath (`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` for `ObjectMapper` and spring Boot's `JacksonAutoConfiguration` should create the `objectMapper` bean)

dependency for maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To find a newer version, please check: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/

Comment: Objectmapper is coming as null

Comment: Is there any problem with the Spring boot version

Comment: @Syed, I've updated my answer to reflect that you need `jackson` in your classpath (gradle/maven) in order to have `objectMapper` bean automatically

Comment: what's the dependency for Jackson for Maven project

Comment: Even after adding the dependency objectmapper is null

Comment: @Syed, you can also ditch the `@Autowired` and just define the field programmatically (i.e. `private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`)

Comment: Yeah in that way I have done it. Thanks for the reply. Pls upvote my question if it make sense.